# How Accurate Laravel "extension" Method Is?

Tags: php, laravel

According to Laravel's documentation you may get a file extension using the `extension()` method from the `UploadedFile` class, but how accurate it is?

From documentation:

> The extension method will attempt to guess the file's extension based
>   on its contents. This extension may be different from the extension
>   that was supplied by the client:

So, what I understand the method is not 100% accurate, but why?, can someone please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't always rely on the extension of a file. I can take any image file, and change the extension to `.docx`. But trying to find the original extension of the file is not that easy.

Most files have a header which depict the type and I think that is what's being used here. But not all files have this. So there is no way of getting the type of any file for sure.

---

**Update:** Laravel uses the [`guessExtension`](https://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_guessExtension) method from Symfony to do this. This method works based on the mime type of a file, which is not always present. And when no mime type is found, Symfony guesses the mime type based on the file's meta data.